# how change text direction(not paragraph alignment) in document in apache poi word?(XWPF)

Tags: text, ms-word, apache-poi, direction

I'm trying to use Apache poi word 3.8 to create word document in persian/arabic language. 
My question is: how change text direction in document? ( it means changing text direction not changing just paragraph text alignment)
In MS Word we could use Right-to-left text direction [image] to change text direction and Align Right [image]to set alignment. What’s equivalent of the first one in poi set property?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is bidirectional text direction support (bidi) and is not yet implemented in apache poi per default. But the underlying object [org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTPPrBase](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.poi/ooxml-schemas/1.1/org/openxmlformats/schemas/wordprocessingml/x2006/main/CTPPrBase.java#CTPPrBase.addNewBidi%28%29) supports this. So we must get this underlying object from the `XWPFParagraph`.

Example:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTP;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTPPr;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STOnOff;

public class CreateWordRTLParagraph {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument doc= new XWPFDocument();

  XWPFParagraph paragraph = doc.createParagraph();
  XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();
  run.setText("Paragraph 1 LTR");

  paragraph = doc.createParagraph();

  CTP ctp = paragraph.getCTP();
  CTPPr ctppr;
  if ((ctppr = ctp.getPPr()) == null) ctppr = ctp.addNewPPr();
  ctppr.addNewBidi().setVal(STOnOff.ON);

  run = paragraph.createRun();
  run.setText("السلام عليكم");

  paragraph = doc.createParagraph();
  run = paragraph.createRun();
  run.setText("Paragraph 3 LTR");
    
  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("WordDocument.docx");
  doc.write(out);
  out.close();
  doc.close();    
 }
}
```