# How to change table direction in Apache word poi (XWPF)?

Tags: ms-word, apache-poi, direction

I'm trying to use Apache poi word 3.8 to create word document in Persian/Arabic language.

My question is: how to change table direction in document? It means order of column in table(not text direction inside table cell).

For example:

[image: rtl table vs lrt table direction]

In MS word we could change table property using:

[image: this option]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how change text direction(not paragraph alignment) in document in apache poi word?(XWPF)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38802115/how-change-text-directionnot-paragraph-alignment-in-document-in-apache-poi-wor)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the whole table shall be bidirectional, then the [org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTTblPr](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.poi/ooxml-schemas/1.1/org/openxmlformats/schemas/wordprocessingml/x2006/main/CTTblPr.java#CTTblPr) must contain `bidiVisual` set to `ON`.

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTP;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTPPr;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STOnOff;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTTcPr;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTTblWidth;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STTblWidth;

import java.math.BigInteger;

public class CreateWordRTLTable {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument doc= new XWPFDocument();

  XWPFParagraph paragraph = doc.createParagraph();
  XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();
  run.setText("Paragraph 1 LTR");

  paragraph = doc.createParagraph();

  //create table:
  XWPFTable table = doc.createTable();
  //set the table itself to bidi visual
  if (table.getCTTbl().getTblPr() == null) {
   table.getCTTbl().addNewTblPr().addNewBidiVisual().setVal(STOnOff.ON);
  } else {
   table.getCTTbl().getTblPr().addNewBidiVisual().setVal(STOnOff.ON);
  }
  //create first row
  XWPFTableRow tableRow = table.getRow(0);
  tableRow.getCell(0).setText("first cell");
  tableRow.addNewTableCell().setText("السلام عليكم");
  tableRow.addNewTableCell().setText("third cell");
  //Each cell contains at least a paragraph. Those can be set to support bidi.
  for (int col = 0 ; col < 3; col++) {
   paragraph = tableRow.getCell(col).getParagraphs().get(0);
   CTP ctp = paragraph.getCTP();
   CTPPr ctppr = ctp.getPPr();
   if (ctppr == null) ctppr = ctp.addNewPPr();
   ctppr.addNewBidi().setVal(STOnOff.ON);
  }

  //create CTTblGrid for this table with widths of the 3 columns. 
  //necessary for Libreoffice/Openoffice to accept the column widths.
  //values are in unit twentieths of a point (1/1440 of an inch)
  table.getCTTbl().addNewTblGrid().addNewGridCol().setW(BigInteger.valueOf(2*1440));
  for (int col = 1 ; col < 3; col++) {
   table.getCTTbl().getTblGrid().addNewGridCol().setW(BigInteger.valueOf(2*1440));
  }

  //create and set column widths for all columns in all rows
  //most examples don't set the type of the CTTblWidth but this
  //is necessary for working in all office versions
  //values are in unit twentieths of a point (1/1440 of an inch)
  for (int col = 0; col < 3; col++) {
   CTTblWidth tblWidth = CTTblWidth.Factory.newInstance();
   tblWidth.setW(BigInteger.valueOf(2*1440));
   tblWidth.setType(STTblWidth.DXA);
   for (int row = 0; row < 1; row++) {
    CTTcPr cttcpr = table.getRow(row).getCell(col).getCTTc().getTcPr();
    if (cttcpr != null) {
     cttcpr.setTcW(tblWidth);
    } else {
     cttcpr = CTTcPr.Factory.newInstance();
     cttcpr.setTcW(tblWidth);
     table.getRow(row).getCell(col).getCTTc().setTcPr(cttcpr);
    }
   }
  }

  paragraph = doc.createParagraph();

  doc.write(new FileOutputStream("WordDocument.docx"));

 }
}
```