# problems with symbols (apostrophe, parenthesis) when writing RTL language with Apache POI XWPFDocument

Tags: java, apache-poi

i've been trying to copy Hebrew data from excel files into a document.
while the letters themselves were copied correctly, it got a betty messy whenever some symbols were involved.

**for example**: instead of *(text)*, i got *)text(*

this is my code so far:

```
XWPFParagraph newPara = document.insertNewParagraph(cursor);
newPara.setAlignment (ParagraphAlignment.RIGHT); 
CTP ctp = newPara.getCTP();
CTPPr ctppr;
if ((ctppr = ctp.getPPr()) == null) ctppr = ctp.addNewPPr();
ctppr.addNewBidi().setVal(STOnOff.ON);
XWPFRun newParaRun = newPara.createRun();
newParaRun.setText(name);
```

i've tried some "bidirectional text direction support" (bidi) lines

(got it from here:
[how change text direction(not paragraph alignment) in document in apache poi word?(XWPF)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38802115/how-change-text-directionnot-paragraph-alignment-in-document-in-apache-poi-wor) )

but it's not that, nor has to do with alignment...

Comment: Cannot reproducing your problem. When I do `run.setText("(שָׁלוֹם)");` instead of `run.setText("السلام عليكم");` in my linked answer, it works correctly. Can you please show a complete example to reproduce your issue?

Comment: well that's strange. i tried it now, exactly with your code and your example, and got )שלום(
the thing is, at System.out.println("(שלום)") it comes out perfectly. the problem is somewhere in the writing to the document.
i've already started to handle it manually with String.replace, but obviously it's far from ideal...

Comment: Sorry, cannot help then. For me it works using my sample code and `run.setText("(שָׁלוֹם)");`. Used `apache poi` was `4.1.2`. It creates a RTL paragraph containing one run having the text (שָׁלוֹם). Tried opening the result `WordDocument.docx` using `Windows 10` and `MS Word` as well as using `Ubuntu Linux` and `Libreoffice Calc`. Both work well.

Comment: that's okay, thanks anyway :)

Comment: Do you open the `*.docx` file using `WordPad`? That results in `)שָׁלוֹם(` for me. But this only shows a disadvantage of `WordPad` which cannot show bidirectional text properly.

Comment: no, Microsoft Word 2007...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using older word processing software applications there seems to be problems when LTR characters and RTL characters gets mixed in one text run. Then using special BiDi character types might be the solution. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bidirectional_text#Table_of_possible_BiDi_character_types.

See also [bidirectional with word document using Aphace POI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61169497/bidirectional-with-word-document-using-aphace-poi/61170607#61170607).

Using this the following works:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTP;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTPPr;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STOnOff;

public class CreateWordRTLParagraph {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument doc= new XWPFDocument();

  XWPFParagraph paragraph = doc.createParagraph();
  XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();
  run.setText("Paragraph 1 LTR");

  paragraph = doc.createParagraph();

  CTP ctp = paragraph.getCTP();
  CTPPr ctppr;
  if ((ctppr = ctp.getPPr()) == null) ctppr = ctp.addNewPPr();
  ctppr.addNewBidi().setVal(STOnOff.ON);

  run = paragraph.createRun();
  String line = "(שָׁלוֹם)";
  run.setText("\u202E" + line + "\u202C");

  paragraph = doc.createParagraph();
  run = paragraph.createRun();
  run.setText("Paragraph 3 LTR");
    
  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("WordDocument.docx");
  doc.write(out);
  out.close();
  doc.close();    
 }
}
```

It uses `U+202E RIGHT-TO-LEFT OVERRIDE (RLO)` before the text line having LTR charcters (`(` and `)`)  and RTL characters (`שָׁלוֹם`) mixed and `U+202C POP DIRECTIONAL FORMATTING (PDF)` after that text line. That tells the word processing software exactly where RTL starts and ends. That leads to correct output for me using `MS Word 365` and `WordPad`.

---

Using `apache poi 5.0.0` for `Bidi` `.setVal(STOnOff.ON)` is not more possible but `.setVal(true)` can be used:

```
  //ctppr.addNewBidi().setVal(STOnOff.ON); // up to apache poi 4.1.2
  ctppr.addNewBidi().setVal(true); // from apache poi 5.0.0 on
```

Comment: really appreciate your effort! still comes out as )שלום( for me though...

Comment: i'll try downloading one of those softwares and see if that works properly there... thanks a lot :)

Comment: it works properly with WordPad. the problem there is that it doesn't show some signature, but i guess that's another problem. thanks a lot!

Comment: so for some reason it doesn't work on microsoft word :/ i've tried so many things. it works okay when i open it on some (not all, but some) other word processors, but they have different problems. is there any other option/direction for fixing it?

Comment: @librogil: Have you tried marking each single LTR- and RTL-block then? For example: `run.setText("\u200E" + "(" + "\u200F" + "שָׁלוֹם" + "\u200E" + ")");`?

Comment: i'm getting the text from a file so it's not really possible. i've used the 2nd code here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61169497/bidirectional-with-word-document-using-aphace-poi/61170607#61170607
but didn't help :(

Comment: to be fair, i'm actually getting an error at the code as it is. i've adjusted it a bit to avoid the error, but maybe my adjustments are the reasons why the code doesn't work properly? here it is:
https://ibb.co/tL8NRL6
1. you can see the error i'm getting from trying to run the code as is.
2. my "adjustments" are the comments here