# Why STOnOff Enums are removed in Apache 5.2.2 ? How to set X_0 & X_1 values?

Tags: java, xml, apache-poi

I was using STOnOff.X_0 Enum to set value as 0(i.e false) for some elements in Apache POI 3.14 when constructing docx file. But now currently in latest version 5.2.2, I could this class has been changed & also new class named as STOnOff1 is being introduced with On & Off enums. Based on below stackoverflow thread I could see that it is suggested to use true or false.

[Similar Stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67027275/problems-with-symbols-apostrophe-parenthesis-when-writing-rtl-language-with-a)

Why is STOnOff class removed & an another class like STOnOff1 is introduced without having STOnOff1.X_0 & STOnOff1.X_1 enums but just STOnOff1.OFF & STOnOff1.ON ? Can I use STTrueFalse.True/STTrueFalse.False in place of just boolean true/false ? Any detailed clarification/solution reg these changes will be really helpful.

**Concrete Examples:**

1)For setEqualWidth(STOnOff value) of Section's column Layout, we could see that previously in POI 3.14 we need to set STOnOff value as STOnOff.X_1, etc.. But in Apache POI 5.2.2 it is now accepting any Object value, **so can we set STTrueFalse.True/boolean true (or) false instead of STOnOff.X_1 in setEqualWidth() API now ?**

**Also could see that any CT API's like setEqualWidth(STOnOff value) which previously accepted STOnOff.Enum values had now changed to accept Object param for which can we pass STTrueFalse.True/STTrueFalse.False instead of plain boolean true(or) false ?**

````
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.officeDocument.x2006.sharedTypes.STOnOff;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.officeDocument.x2006.sharedTypes.STTrueFalse;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTPageMar;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTSectPr;

public class STOnOffValuesTesting {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        try {
        byte[] docbytes = FileUtil.read("anysimpleDocxFile.docx"); //No i18n
        InputStream documentStream = GeneralUtils.getStreamFromArray( docbytes );
        XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument( documentStream );
        List<CTSectPr> documentSections = document.docSections;
        int length = documentSections.size();

        for(int i=0; i <length; i++){
            CTSectPr sectPr = documentSections.get(i);

            //In Apache POI 3.14
            sectPr.getCols().setEqualWidth(STOnOff.X_1);
            

            //But in Apache POI 5.2.2
            sectPr.getCols().setEqualWidth(true);
            sectPr.getCols().setEqualWidth(STTrueFalse.TRUE); //Is this correct ?
            }
        }catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e)
        }
    }
}```
````

Comment: I guess it is because according to the XML specification of [xmlschema-2#boolean](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#boolean) there is no difference between `true` and `1` or `false` and `0`. But I am not part of the `apache poi` developer team. I am a user only. But what exactly is the case where `false` not works but `0` would work?

Comment: [Alex Richter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3915431/axel-richter) Thanks a lot. Both false & 0 would work, my query was just related to understanding the reason/logic behind these changes. So, instead of setting boolean true/False can I set STTrueFalse.True/STTrueFalse.False Enum values in place of STOnOff.Enum ? Is that fine ?

Comment: No, `STTrueFalse` and `STOnOff` are not the same. So the one cannot be used in place of the other. Whether the one or the other needs to be used is determined by the context. But again, try to ask about a **concrete** use case and not as vague.

Comment: [Alex Ritcher](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3915431/axel-richter) Okk thanks a lot for swift reply. My bad, newbie in posting questions at stack-overflow, have modified question & added concrete examples for reference.

Comment: The `ST` and `CT` classes are auto-generated by Apache XMLBeans based on the XSDs that Microsoft publish for the OOXML file formats. Most of the strange bits in the XML can be traced back to strange things in the file format specs...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the low level `Office Open XML`-schemas classes, a programmer needs to know in detail what those classes are doing. That's the aim of `apache poi`: To provide a high level layer to use those low level classes.

**Where are the `Office Open XML`-schemas classes coming from?**

Those classes are generated form `XSD` files which are published in  [ECMA-376](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications-and-standards/standards/ecma-376/). They are contained in download part 4. The `XSD`s contain definitions for the `XML` which gets used in `Office Open XML`. [XMLBeans](https://xmlbeans.apache.org/) from Apache provides methods to auto-generate `Java` classes from this `XSD`s. So the low-level `Office Open XML`-schemas classes of `ooxml-schemas` or `poi-ooxml-lite` or `poi-ooxml-full` do fully translate the given `XSD` definitions to `Java`.

So the general answer to your question about the reason of changes in this `Office Open XML`-schemas classes is that the published `XSD`s have changed from 1st edition in 2006 up to 4th edition in 2012. Or the used `XMLBeans` version has changed and does the `XSD` - `Java` - translation a little bit different.

**`STOnOff` versus `STTrueFalse`**

The `XML` type `ST_OnOff` was defined in 1st edition of `wml.xsd` as an enumeration of "true", "false", "on", "off", "1", "0". Now in 4th edition it is defined in `shared-commonSimpleTypes.xsd` as [xsd:boolean](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#boolean) and `ST_OnOff1`, where `ST_OnOff1` is an enumeration of "on", "off". This is probably done because `xsd:boolean` contains "true", "false", "1", "0" already. So it can replace the former used enumeration.

The `XML` type `ST_TrueFalse` was defined in 1th edition of `vml-main.xsd` as an enumeration of "t", "f", "true", "false". Now in 4th edition it is defined in `shared-commonSimpleTypes.xsd` also as an enumeration of "t", "f", "true", "false". But it only gets used in `VML`.

So `STTrueFalse` and `STOnOff` are not the same. The one cannot be used in place of the other. Whether the one or the other needs to be used is determined by the context. It is defined by `XML` types which use either the `ST_TrueFalse` or the `ST_OnOff` type. For example the type `CT_OnOff` in wordprocessing which uses `ST_OnOff` or multiple `VML` types which use `ST_TrueFalse`.

In terms of  `Java` and `CTSectPr` - `CTColumns.setEqualWidth` one can simply test this using following code using `apache poi 5.2.2`:

```
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTSectPr;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTColumns;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.officeDocument.x2006.sharedTypes.STTrueFalse;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.officeDocument.x2006.sharedTypes.STOnOff1;

class STOnOffValuesTesting {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  CTSectPr sectPr = CTSectPr.Factory.newInstance();
  CTColumns cols = sectPr.addNewCols();
  cols.setEqualWidth(true); //cols.setEqualWidth(false); // works and gets used by Apache POI by default
  System.out.println(sectPr);
  cols.setEqualWidth("1"); //cols.setEqualWidth("0"); // works and gets used by Microsoft by default
  System.out.println(sectPr);
  cols.setEqualWidth(STOnOff1.ON); //cols.setEqualWidth(STOnOff1.OFF); // works but never gets used by Microsoft instead of boolean 
  System.out.println(sectPr);
  //cols.setEqualWidth(STTrueFalse.TRUE); //cols.setEqualWidth(STTrueFalse.FALSE); // will not work as STTrueFalse only gets used in VML
 }
}
```

The `cols.setEqualWidth(STTrueFalse.TRUE)` throws an exception. The `cols.setEqualWidth(STOnOff1.ON)` works per definition. But I would not use this because Microsoft Word itself never uses "on"/"off" in this context.

Comment: Thanks a lot [Alex Ritcher](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3915431/axel-richter).  It's clear now that as per latest Xm Schemas STTrueFalse & STOnOff cannot be used in place of each other. But how were u able to confirm that MS Word uses "0" or "1" by default ? In MSWord OpenXML SDK [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.columns.equalwidth?view=openxml-2.8.1#documentformat-openxml-wordprocessing-columns-equalwidth), it is mentioned any values of true' or 'false', 'on' or 'off', or '0' or '1'. Am I missing something here, correct me if wrong?

Comment: [Alex Ritcher](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3915431/axel-richter) So, we can use either "0"/"1" or else boolean true/false in place of STOnOff. For STTrueFalse it can be used as such without any alternatives in it's context in VML ? Is this fine ?

Comment: @logesh ramasamy: "how to confirm that MS Word uses "0" or "1" by default?": By looking into the XML which Microsoft Word generates. The `*.xlsx` files are ZIP archives. You can unzip them and have a look into `/word/document.xml`. Otherwise, yes, that is as I would understand it too.

Comment: Thanks a lot [Alex Ritcher](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3915431/axel-richter) :-)